# Converting with ffmpeg a bunch of webinars that contains a lot of slides (still images) aside a webcam speaker/lecturer

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, compression, h.265, av1

I screen recorded a lot of webinars that now I have to compress in order to have less space occupied.

The content of this webinars are mostly persons talking like in zoom, few pixels of them in webcam and the rest of the screen is a power point or acrobat presentation with still images that lasts like 10 minutes during the explanation of the lecturer.

I would like to compress them in h265 to retain the best quality possible but at the same time the smallest amount of data.

Given the fact the most of the frame is a still image make no sense use a fixed style bitrate, I would like to know if there's a specific setting for ffmpeg libx265 in order to save the best amount possible of space having the data mostly occupied for the scene change and repeating the frame part for the rest of the time.

Tried to use:
ffmpeg -i "input_h264.mp4" -t 20 -filter:v "crop=1600:1078:0:77" -c:v libx265 -crf 23 -preset slow -tune stillimage -profile main -c:a aac -b:a 192k "out_h265.mp4"

But ffmpeg says: Error setting preset/tune medium/stillimage.

Reading the libx265 implementation probably the preset stillimage isn't there, there's a "animation" preset, but I'm not sure that this could work for my the case.

My guess is that this could be a situation where use a very long GOP.

Do you think I should give up with preset and setup libx265-params manually? and if so what of them?

**BONUS:
Can you provide the same answer if using the libx264 and the av1 codecs?**

Thanks